# No module named ogr

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to use `ogr` module, I tried to install it with pip got the errors :

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `ogr` (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for `ogr`

tried to install all the package including GDAL and still getting an error

> "No module named `ogr`.

didn't find a working solution on google.

That's the code i'm trying to run:

```
    import ogr,csv,sys
import shapefile
shpfile=sys.argv[1]
# csvfile=r'C:\Temp\test.csv' #sys.argv[2]
#Open files
csvfile=open('converterOutput.csv','wb')
ds=ogr.Open(shpfile)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()

#Get field names
dfn=lyr.GetLayerDefn()
nfields=dfn.GetFieldCount()
fields=[]
for i in range(nfields):
    fields.append(dfn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
fields.append('kmlgeometry')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fields)
try:csvwriter.writeheader() #python 2.7+
except:csvfile.write(','.join(fields)+'\n')

# Write attributes and kml out to csv
for feat in lyr:
    attributes=feat.items()
    geom=feat.GetGeometryRef()
    attributes['kmlgeometry']=geom.ExportToKML()
    csvwriter.writerow(attributes)

#clean up
del csvwriter,lyr,ds
csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows:

Go to the [gisinternals site](https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) select the download link for you architecture and compiler, search for the `Generic installer for the GDAL core components` msi, download and install as `typical`.

You have two options, the second requires that you have `pip` installed and the first one must set the path variables.

1.) Download the `Installer for the GDAL python bindings (requires to install the GDAL core)` msi, and install.

Open cmd and type:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL"
setx PATH "%GDAL_DATA%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data"
setx PATH "%GDAL_DRIVER_PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins"
```

*Note that each one of the commands above is a separate one, so copy-paste and enter, each one separately. If you downloaded the x64 version just remove the (x86).

OR

2.) Go to [the unofficial python wheels site](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) search for the version that matches the core you have already installed, download.
Then, copy the path to the file you just donwloaded, in my case:

```
C:\Users\admin\donwloads\GDAL‑2.2.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Once you have the path, type windows key plus r, than cmd, enter and type:

```
pip install "your path to the wheel you have downloaded"
```

in my case it looks something like:

```
pip install C:\Users\admin\donwloads\GDAL‑2.2.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl (look where the file is located).
```

To test just run a cmd and type:

```
python
```

Once you are in the python shell:

```
import gdal
```

If you need to install the library for Mac, take a look at [the tutorial written by me](https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython), or add a comment so that I update the answer.

References: [UCLA](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows#Installing_GDAL_for_Windows)

Comment: none of the options worked for me....Not even the tutorial..Any suggestion?

Comment: @Oalvinegro care to elaborate?

Comment: Your solution in #1 worked well for me. It was one of may fixes I did to get a tool called [GDBee](https://github.com/AlexArcPy/GDBee/blob/master/README.md) working. It was quite a journey: [Install and run GDBee file geodatabase SQL tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447090/install-and-run-gdbee-file-geodatabase-sql-tool#:~:text=about%20that%20error.-,Edit%202,-%3A). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Please first install python GDAL package then import something like this

```
 from osgeo import ogr
```

Or you can follow below link
[https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/]

Comment: Only getting errors: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'"