# Error when installing osmnx (A GDAL API version must be specified) problem

Tags: python, osmnx

I want to install osmnx, I wrote `pip install osmnx` in cmd, but it returns me an error:

```
C:\Users\Horseman.mini>pip install osmnx
Collecting osmnx
Using cached     https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/77/98cbee7f94abe2c60013fd8751f2b2d6054d48078c61f9774cff0b341f43/osmnx-0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in     c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from osmnx) (1.17.4)
Collecting networkx>=2.3
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/8f/dd6a8e85946def36e4f2c69c84219af0fa5e832b018c970e92f2ad337e45/networkx-2.4-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Shapely>=1.6 in     c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from osmnx) (1.6.4.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.21 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from osmnx) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from osmnx) (0.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.2 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from osmnx) (3.1.2)
Collecting Rtree>=0.8.3
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/2f/9dc53cfb8edb32a0fb89e689f89e3b4c1a4455652032386fd2dd034c711a/rtree-0.9.1-0_py37hbf79ddb-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (3.8MB)
 |████████████████████████████████| 3.8MB 595kB/s
Collecting descartes>=1.1
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/b6/1ed2eb03989ae574584664985367ba70cd9cf8b32ee8cad0e8aaeac819f3/descartes-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting geopandas>=0.5
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/0c/e6c99e561b03482220f00443f610ccf4dce9b50f4b1093d735f93c6fc8c6/geopandas-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.3->osmnx) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.21->osmnx) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.21->osmnx) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.21->osmnx) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.21->osmnx) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.24->osmnx) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.24->osmnx) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->osmnx) (2.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->osmnx) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->osmnx) (1.1.0)
Collecting fiona
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/f4/0a0ddc6174c4a93679b5f1dd3535e7ef8989828e6d5f86112de681f8c87b/Fiona-1.8.11.tar.gz
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HORSEM~1.MIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ecd90yd9\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HORSEM~1.MIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ecd90yd9\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HORSEM~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecd90yd9\fiona\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\HORSEM~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecd90yd9\fiona\
Complete output (1 lines):
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I use windows 10, python versions: 2.7 and 3.7

I don't understand what should I do to successfully install osmnx, what should I specify and how? (The same A GDAL API version must be specified problem I have when I try to install geopandas). I'd be greatful for your help!

**EDIT 1:**
I can freely import gdal after installing, but after I do:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL"
setx PATH "%GDAL_DATA%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal-data"
setx PATH "%GDAL_DRIVER_PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins"
```

I cannot use pip and python commands in cmd anymore so I can't do `pip install osmnx`! If I don't setx all this it returns me the same error as it was in the begining.

**EDIT 2:**
I used repair in the python installer and it gave me back my pip and python commands in cmd. After installing gdal it imports good, but after `pip install osmnx` it returns me the same error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HORSEM~1.MIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iqd4diwx\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HORSEM~1.MIN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iqd4diwx\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HORSEM~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iqd4diwx\fiona\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\HORSEM~1.MIN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iqd4diwx\fiona\
Complete output (1 lines):
A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a 
GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

As far as I understand I installed gdal but gdal version didn't specified yet. What I haven't done yet or do wrong? [I found some info](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal-config.html), maybe it will be helpful

Comment: You have to set the GDAL environment variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059373/no-module-named-ogr/58281021#58281021

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez please see my Edit 1

Comment: You can do it manually if it messing things up, look up on google how to set environment variables, the first thing in between the % is the path and the next is the value to set.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez see edit 2, please. I returned python and pip commands, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Would you mind running a batch script that I wrote that does that?

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez wait, I need to specify in env variables path to gdal-config folder? I have no files named gdal-config!

Comment: https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows#Installing_GDAL_for_Windows

Comment: When you have installed GDAL, use this batch script to add the paths automatically: https://felipunky.github.io/Scripts/GIS/GDALPATH.bat

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez I installed GDAL successfully and added paths.. If I type gdalinfo --version in cmd it returns me GDAL 2.4.1, released 2019/03/15. When I exec bat file it writes syntax error and variables set. But I have the same error about GDAL_CONFIG

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez I added paths from tutorial you send 19 min ago

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez maybe you could see the core of the problem if you watch it in TeamViewer?

Comment: Can your run ogr2ogr from the cmd?

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez yes, it returns me its usage ..etc

Comment: You probably need to add another environment variable to GDAL_VERSION with the version you installed

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez and what should be its path?

Comment: Try running `gdalinfo --version` on the cmd and add the version an evironment variable. `GDAL_VERSION=2.2.4` in my case

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez returns GDAL 2.4.2, released 2019/06/28. What should be the name of the variable and its path ?

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez I mean how to add the version

Comment: The variable is `GDAL_VERSION` and the value is the version number.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez It works. Now I have no error related with gdal_version

Comment: I am gonna add it as an answer then.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez marked as a solution. Thank you! BTW do you know how to install fiona? I have a little problem with it when installing osmnx

Comment: No, I haven't used Fiona or osmx, I mostly use the C# GDAL bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install and set environment variables for [GDAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059373/no-module-named-ogr/58281021#58281021), on top of the ones mentioned in the question, you must also add a `GDAL_VERSION` environment variable with the version you have already installed, you can check which one it is by running `gdalinfo --version` from the cmd, in my case the value of the environment variable would be `GDAL_VERSION=2.2.4`, it might change depending on which version you installed.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what should I do to successfully install osmnx, what should I specify and how?

Note that the OSMnx installation [instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) provide easy step-by-step instructions. You don't have to do any complicated GDAL configuring, etc.