# Python - pip install - ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified

Tags: python, module

I try to install the module contextily to use it on Python.

I went on Anaconda Prompt as admin, and wrote : pip install contextily

I get this error and I have still not found what I have to do :

> Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
>    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>         command:'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe'
>   'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py'
>   get_requires_for_build_wheel
>   'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwkajt8gq'
>          cwd: C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ysq517b2\rasterio
>   Complete output (2 lines):
>   INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More
>   information is available in the README.
>   ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG
>
> ### environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe'
>   'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py'
>   get_requires_for_build_wheel
>   'C:\Users\elise\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwkajt8gq' Check the logs for full command output.

(I tried to deal with environment variable like there : [No module named ogr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059373/no-module-named-ogr/58281021#58281021) but it doesn't help. Neither these solutions : [Error installing geopandas:" A GDAL API version must be specified " in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54734667/error-installing-geopandas-a-gdal-api-version-must-be-specified-in-anaconda))

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command using anaconda prompt:
`conda install -c conda-forge contextily`

You can find the [documentation here.](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/contextily)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to install packages that I couldn't before, by creating a virtual environment and working on it (it's simple on Anaconda Navigator : Environments/Create, and then using the right part of the navigator to install new packages)